# Animating Glare angle offset

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

Is it possible to animate the "Angle offset" property of the Glare node? I am making a photon torpedo that has a glare applied to it, which should rotate when the torpedo is on the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of Blenders properties can be animated. Just hover over the **Angle Offset** field with your mouse and press <kbd>I</kbd> to insert a keyframe. A keyframe will be inserted on the current frame. Move to another frame, change the value and insert another keyframe by pressing <kbd>I</kbd> again.

The created key will show up in the dopesheet and graph editor, where you can edit/remove them.